# Unable to receive all data when concat two observables in rxjs

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I created two observables from a database:

```
const roomData$ = estab
      .query()
      .where('estab.type', 'like', 'rooms')
      .then((rooms) => {
        rooms.forEach((room) => {
          observer.next(room.data);
        });
      });
  }).map(data => ({
    roomsData: [
      ...data.rooms,
    ],
  }));
const hotelData$ = Observable.create((observer) => {
        estab
          .query()
          .where('estab.type', 'like', 'hotels')
          .then((hotels) => {
            hotels.forEach((hotel) => {
              observer.next(hotel.data);
            });
          });
      }).map(data => ({
        hotelsData: [
          ...data.hotels,
        ],
      }));  
const hotelContentData$ = Observable.concat(roomData$, hotelData$);
hotelContentData$.subscribe((data) =>  {
    fs.appendFile('data.json', (err) => { 
         if (err) throw err;
         console.log('file has been appended!);
   }      
})
```

In the `data.json` file I found only the data received from the `roomData$` observable. I change the order in `Observable.concat(hotelData$, roomData$)` and now I get the data of hotel observable. Why only one Observable is executed? How can I execute both of them and get data from `hotelData$` and `roomData$`?

Comment: The `concat` operator subscribes to only one Observable at a time. So if you want data from all of them you need to be sure they properly `complete`. Otherwise you could use `zip(...).take(1)` if you're expecting for example just one emission from each of them. Or maybe the `merge` operator is better for your usecase.

Comment: @martin I tried `concat` operator and I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

`Observable.concat` will take emissions from a stream until that stream completes, and then move to the next stream. Since you're creating your own observable sequences, be sure to complete each one.

```
const roomData$ = Observable.create( observer => {
  estab
    .query()
    .where('estab.type', 'like', 'rooms')
    .then((rooms) => {
      rooms.forEach((room) => {
        observer.next(room.data);
      });
      observer.complete(); // adding this will complete your stream.
    });
}).map(data => ({
  roomsData: [
    ...data.rooms,
  ],
}));

const hotelData$ = Observable.create((observer) => {
  estab
    .query()
    .where('estab.type', 'like', 'hotels')
    .then((hotels) => {
      hotels.forEach((hotel) => {
        observer.next(hotel.data);
      });
      observer.complete(); // adding this will complete your stream.
    });
}).map(data => ({
  hotelsData: [
    ...data.hotels,
  ],
}));

const hotelContentData$ = Observable.concat(roomData$, hotelData$);
hotelContentData$.subscribe((data) =>  {
  fs.appendFile('data.json', (err) => { 
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('file has been appended!);
  });      
});
```

Comment: I tried your proposition and I got only the data of `roomData$` not all the data.